# Duplicate invoice number issue on bulk entry through multiple curl post request at same time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to insert bulk orders via curl. For each order, the invoice number is generated incrementing the previously inserted invoice number in Order table.

**Order Table**

```
Create Table tOrder
(
   OrderUID Int NOT NULL AutoIncrement,
   OrderNumber  Varchar(12) NOT NULL ,
   CreatedBy Int,
   CreatedOn DateTime,
   Primary Key(OrderUID)
);
```

Sample ordernumber formats:
ULEN21000001
UCMC21000002

The last 6 digits is considered for incrementing the sequence during order generation.

> SELECT Right(OrderNumber,6) FROM tOrders ORDER BY tOrders.OrderUID DESC LIMIT 1;

**Issue I am facing:**
While inserting single order or bulk insert (from single curl request) it is working. But when inserting bulk orders by triggering curl post from various system at same time. Duplicate OrderNumbers are inserted into order table.
For eg.,
30 orders from system A and 15 orders from system B and so on.

> Select * from tOrder;

| OrderUID | OrderNumber | CreatedBy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UABC210001 | 1 |
| 2 | UABC210001 | 1 |
| 3 | UABD210002 | 2 |
| 4 | UABC210003 | 2 |
| 5 | UABC210003 | 3 |
| 6 | UABE210004 | 3 |
| 7 | UABE210004 | 3 |

**What I have tried:**
1)In PHP,
I getting all the request in array and looping through each row and generating OrderNumber and inserting into tOrder table.

```
 foreach($Orders as $order)
{
  $this->db->trans_begin();

  $insArr =[
  'OrderNumber' => $this->GenerateOrderNo(), //Order generation
  'CreatedBy'   => 1,    
  ];

  $this->db->insert('tOrder',$insArr);
  $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

  if ($this->db->trans_status() === false) {
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
  } else {
    $this->db->trans_commit();
    /* regenerating and updating if already exists */
    if($this->OrderExists($insArr['OrderNumber']))
    {
      $insArr =[
      'OrderNumber' => $this->GenerateOrderNo(), //Order re-generation      
      ];
      $this->db->where('OrderUID',$insert_id);
      $this->db->update('tOrder',$insArr);
    }
  }
}
```

2. In MySql,
   I have written a trigger to generate OrderNumber before inserting into table.

> CREATE TRIGGER `Insert_OrderNumber` BEFORE INSERT ON `tOrders`
> FOR
> EACH ROW BEGIN
> SELECT    Right(OrderNumber,6) INTO @LastOrderNo
> FROM tOrders ORDER BY tOrders.OrderUID DESC LIMIT 1;
>
> SELECT LPAD(@LastOrderNo + 1, 6,0) INTO @NewSequenceNo;
> SET NEW.OrderNumber = @NewSequenceNo;
> END

I have also tried to add unique index for OrderNumber column.
In such case, OrderEntry fails with error.

Please correct me, where I am wrong or any alternate suggestions.

.

Comment: Use an autoincrement column for the numeric part and store the prefix characters in a separate column. Combine together in a SELECT query if you need to see the full ID. With an autoincrement the database guarantees unique values for you

Comment: @ADyson Tha if the order is deleted and again created then the ordernumber continuation will become issue on this approach. Will try your suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by "order number continuation" exactly? It's not clear what you're describing or why it would be a problem. Please clarify your worry.

Comment: @ADyson Required continuous number. For eg., 1st order - C2TM21000001, 2nd order - D3TN21000002, and so on Z5TN21000N (N = lastnumber). Here the last 6 digits is continuous despite the prefix (first 6 digits). In case of auto increment, if I delete then last number, and create a new order then the generated number would be N+1. As of now the current logic works when the request is from single system. Actual duplicate issue happens only when the request is from multiple system simultaneously.

Comment: Why do the numbers need to be continuous? What problem does that solve for you? The purpose of an ID is to be _unique_ and represent _one_ item only, _forever_. If you re-use a number which has previously been deleted, then you'll break that golden rule. And then if a customer comes to complain about their order, and gives you the ID, you might find they're talking about an order you've now deleted, and you're talking about different order which has re-used the same ID. That's a recipe for problems (including bigger ones than the simple example I've just given)...

Comment: ...And auto-increment fields exist for several reasons - firstly to solve the race condition issue you're currently experiencing when adding rows from several systems simultaneously, and secondly to ensure that IDs are unique for the entity in the table, and cannot be re-used (accidentally or on purpose), regardless of whether a record has been deleted. There are other reasons too. But basically - they solve your problem, so please use it. Having continuous numbers at all times is _not_ a useful requirement - in fact it causes problems instead of solving them, as I've explained.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest changing you table structure so that you store the order prefix instead of the whole order number (6 chars instead of 12 and not storing the sequence twice in the same table) -

```
CREATE TABLE `tOrder` (
  `OrderUID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `OrderPrefix` CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `CreatedOn` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrderUID`));
```

There is no need to have another sequence for the order number as you already have your OrderUID column. So when accessing the table you can just -

```
SELECT
    OrderUID,
    CONCAT(OrderPrefix, LPAD(OrderUID, 6, '0')) AS OrderNumber,
    CreatedBy,
    CreatedOn
FROM tOrder;
```

or just save this query as a view -

```
CREATE VIEW `vw_orders` AS
SELECT
    OrderUID,
    CONCAT(OrderPrefix, LPAD(OrderUID, 6, '0')) AS OrderNumber,
    CreatedBy,
    CreatedOn
FROM tOrder;
```

You did not include the source for your `GenerateOrderNo()` method in your original post. I suspect it would be a reasonable approach to drop the OrderPrefix from the tOrder table and replace it with a foreign key to the object referenced by your order prefix.

Comment: Hi @nnichols, thanks. I didn't include the GenerateOrderNo(), because it is similar to the trigger which i have mentioned. Just taking the last 6 digits of previous order and incrementing it, and appending prefix. I have little hesitation with this approach. Suppose if the order is deleted and again created then the ordernumber continuation will be skipped. Irrespective of prefix, the continuation ordernumber is required. Here the duplicate numbers inserted only when the function is triggered parallely from different systems.

Comment: @DSP The problem with your method for managing the sequence is that it is not safe when you have concurrent requests.  Multiple clients will SELECT the same LastOrderNo value which is why they are using the same numeric value when setting the NEW.OrderNumber, whether in your PHP code or the trigger. For your method to work you would have to have a lock held for the read and consequent insert so that no other client session could read the same value. This would then mean you could have lots of blocking requests against your tOrder table.

Comment: I do not understand your need for contiguous order numbers. You probably should not allow hard deletes of orders as that would potentially allow for multiple orders with the same numeric ID - original deleted and then new order created with same ID.